# Why concurrent "Delete...Insert" statements cause a deadlock?

Tags: mysql, transactions

Consider the following schema in mysql:

```sql
create table foo(
  id int not null primary key auto_increment,
  name varchar(32) not null,
  unique key(name)
);
```

And there is a record with name "abc" in the table.

I have a transaction (RC):

```sql
start transaction;
delete from foo where name = "abc";
insert into foo(name) values("abc");
commit;
```

If there are two concurrent transactions, the dead lock will happen.

```
       |        TX A         |             TX B
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Step 1 | start transaction;  | 
       | delete name="abc";  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Step 2 |                     | start transaction;
       |                     | delete name="abc";
       |                     | <wait for lock>
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Step 3 | insert name="abc";  | <deadlock detected, exit>
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Step 4 | commit;             |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm wondering why this sequence causes the deadlock.

In the mysql doc says (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html)

> If a duplicate-key error occurs, a shared lock on the duplicate index
>   record is set. This use of a shared lock can result in deadlock should
>   there be multiple sessions trying to insert the same row if another 
>   session already has an exclusive lock. This can occur if another session
>   deletes the row.

I suppose when transaction A runs the "delete" statement, it has acquired the X lock of the record "abc". When the "insert" statement executes, it tries to acquire the S lock due to the "duplicate key error". Shouldn't it get the S lock since it has got the X lock of the same record? Why deadlock happens here?

Comment: with `delete ....` i assume you always mean`delete from foo where name = "abc";` and with `insert ...` i assume you always mean `insert into foo(name) values("abc");`

Comment: `DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...` sets an exclusive next-key lock on every record the search encounters. However, only an **index record lock is required for statements that lock rows using a unique index to search for a unique row**.

Comment: yes，your assumption is correct.

Comment: `TX A` holds because of `DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...` a unique index lock on the value `"abc"` .. `TX B` also tryes to delete with "abc" but transaction `TX A` "invalidates" `TX B` delete transaction state when `TX A` does that insert  with "abc"  whats why `TX B` deadlocks as `TX A` holds the rights of "abc" (more or less as it is simplified a bit)

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the deadlock, and got the innoDB status log as follow:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2019-10-18 18:35:14 0x7f1dfc738700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 26547965, ACTIVE 6 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
/* ApplicationName=DataGrip 2019.1.1 */ delete from foo where name='abc'
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 3011 page no 4 n bits 224 index IDX_NAME of table `foo` trx id 26547965 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 153 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; ....

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 26547960, ACTIVE 10 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
/* ApplicationName=DataGrip 2019.1.1 */ INSERT INTO foo(id, name)
VALUES (1, 'abc')
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 3011 page no 4 n bits 224 index IDX_NAME of table `foo` trx id 26547960 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 153 PHYSICAL RECORD: ...

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 3011 page no 4 n bits 224 index IDX_NAME of table `foo` trx id 26547960 lock mode S waiting
Record lock, heap no 153 PHYSICAL RECORD: ....

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

The log explains the reason clearly, TX B waiting X lock held by TX A, at the same time, TX A waiting S lock which is block by TX B's lock request.

According to Mysql doc:

> If a duplicate-key error occurs, a shared lock on the duplicate index record is set. This use of a shared lock can result in deadlock should there be multiple sessions trying to insert the same row if another session already has an exclusive lock. "

Insert statement does acquire S lock at some point, so the reason for why deadlock happens is very clear.

**But problem is:**

- according to the mysql doc, insert statement will acquire a S lock if a duplicate-key error occurs, which is not happened in current case we discuss
- why insert statement still acquire a S lock when current transaction already holds the X lock, X lock is enough for doing a current read to check the duplicate key error. so what does it use for ?